# Nginx is not allowing more than 350 concurrent requests to it's home page

Tags: nginx, virtual-machine, nginx-config

I have a VM for Nginx set up with 8 virtual processors and 8 sockets, having the following Nginx configuration.

here is the Nginx configuration

```
worker_processes  16;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  xyz.domain.com;


        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }



       server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  xyz.domain.com;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

         gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level    5;
    gzip_min_length    256;
    gzip_proxied       any;
    gzip_vary          on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_buffers 32 16k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types image/jpeg application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript ;

    gzip_types
    application/atom+xml
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/ld+json
    application/manifest+json
    application/rss+xml
    application/vnd.geo+json
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    application/x-font-ttf
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/xml
    font/opentype
    image/bmp
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon
    text/cache-manifest
    text/css
    text/plain
    text/vcard
    text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
    text/vtt
    text/x-component
    text/x-cross-domain-policy;

        ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  privatekey.key;





    }

}
```

used Jmeter to hit concurrently Nginx home page, it only works up to 350 parallel requests later it gives connection refused error. It doesn't really has any proxy pass or upstream configuration, just hitting Nginx home page for 400 times gives errors, How can I increase this limit to around 10000 at least, changing worker connections in the config doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Minor suggestion - the easier you make it for ppl to help, the more likely you are to get help.  At least half of the conf file you'e shown us is commented out - so why include it here? It just makes it harder for us to read and parse.

Comment: sure I will keep that in mind, thanks, also removed the comments from configuration